# Cookiecutter command on git repo with template returning error

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, cookiecutter-django, cookiecutter

I am trying to run `cookiecutter https://github.com/user/template` (user is the account and template is the repository that contains the cookiecutter template I created) in an empty repo but whenever I try to run the command, I receive this error:

```
    USER:empty-repo $ cookiecutter https://github.com/user/template
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://user@github.com': 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/bin/cookiecutter", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/cli.py", line 152, in main
    skip_if_file_exists=skip_if_file_exists,
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/main.py", line 74, in cookiecutter
    directory=directory,
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/repository.py", line 114, in determine_repo_dir
    no_input=no_input,
  File "/Users/aos/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cookiecutter/vcs.py", line 104, in clone
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 487, in run
    output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/user/template.git']' returned non-zero exit status 128.
```

Does this have to do that the repo and/or account being private? I have looked at some places but not sure on a solution. Anything would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Cookiecutter 0.7.2

Python 3.7

Comment: Try `git clone https://github.com/user/template.git` from the command line — what is the full error?

Comment: Cloning the repo from the command line produces this: `Cloning into 'template'...
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://user@github.com':
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/user/template.git/'` HTTP doesn't let me clone it but SSH will. Maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Most probably..